# Mongoose: Designing a Relational Schema Properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am trying to set up some relational data between a few objects in my mongodb/monogoose database using references (storing ID in properties.) I have written what I have implemented and my shortcomings. This is an expansive post, please see my TL;DR before reading everything. 
High level answers with some code is acceptable as well.

I have the following schemas in my Mongoose database:

User:

```
UserSchema: {
    _id: (MongoID)
    isActive:
    firstName:
    lastName:
    email: 
    phone:
    role: 
    hash:
    address:
}
```

Vehicle:

```
VehicleSchema: {
    _id: (MongoID)
    internal_id: (linking id)
    metadata: (product name, product description)
}
```

Value:

```
ValueSchema: {
    _id: (MongoID)
    internal_id: (linking id)
    todayPrice: xxx.xx
    history [ {...}, {...}, {...}]
}
```

Each `user` has a `garage`, a place they can store their `vehicles` of type `VehicleSchema`. The `vehicle` <--> `garage` relationship needs the following functionality:

1. A `user` can `CRUD` `vehicles` to his `garage` (one at a time).

suggestion; add (C**D) the following to `UserSchema`:

`garage: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Vehicle' }]`

```
UserSchema.methods.addToGarage= function (id) {
    if (this.garage.indexOf(id) === -1) {
        this.garage.push(id);
     }
    return this.save();
};
UserSchema.methods.removeFromGarage= function (id) {
    this.garage.remove(id);
    return this.save();
};
UserSchema.methods.isInGarage= function (id) {
    return this.garage.some(function (vehicleId) {
        return vehicleId.toString() === id.toString();
    });
};
```

I am having trouble developing the "R" (read) of `CRUD` for my `garage`, but I have a starting point:

```
UserSchema.methods.viewGarage= function (id) {
    return this.garage; // only Ids? how do I include the actual document?
};
```

I was thinking maybe using the `_id` property of the vehicle(s) in the `user's` `garage` and using them to match a `Vehicles.find({})` query.

2. An admin should be able to run a query which can get the frequency of `_id` of `vehicle` in `garages`.

Query: get all `vehicles` from the `garages` of all the `users` and count frequency. Return a (sorted) array of `vehicle` and times in garage.

starting point -- use an aggregate query:

```
 User.aggregate([
    { 
       $lookup: 
         {
            from: "vehicle",
            localField: "garage", // ?? attempt: garage.forEach()
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "vehicle"
         } 
     }
  ])
```

Here I am stuck going from `users --> users.garage[] --> vehicle --> vehicle.internal_id`, and then counting the `_ids` into a frequency chart.

3. `vehicle` and `value` are objects which share the same `internal_id` key/value pair. (these objects are merged using `$lookup`.) Here's where it gets important. The admin is able to run a script which updates `Values` if there is a change in price:

   ```
   Values.find({}).then(docs => {
    docs.forEach(value => {
       request((myUrl, value) => {
           // update logic here
           if (update) { // if there is an update
                value.save();
                // VALUE SCHEMA WAS UPDATED
           }
       });
    }});
   ```

when `ValueSchema` is updated --> I need to notify each user that there was a change in value. In order to do that, I need a list of all users who have the updated `vehicle.internal_id` in their `garage,` [ user --> garage[] --> vehicle <--> value] and be able to iterate over that list. 
I'm having trouble creating this list of users who's `Value` from `Vehicle` in their `garage` was updated.

TL;DR:

1. What is best practice to implement value <--> vehicle <--> garage <--> user relationship?
2. How do I return the vehicles stored in garage by reference?
3. How can I get the frequency of cars saved in garages? (think of garage as favorites list.)
4. How can I create a notification system with these relationships? (Notify user of update, e.x. this.sendEmail(user.email) )